Circular Array - Incoming Wave angle for a Polygon
I am trying to calculate the angle of a plane sound wave arriving at a circular array. A circular array has $M$ receiving elements that are lying on a circle with radius R and the distance between each element to the next neighbor element is described with $d$.
In my case I do some preprocessing and get the information about the time of arrival $\tau_m$ at each element $m$ of the array. With these timings I can calculate the time difference of arrival for receiving element pairs (for example $\Delta\tau_{i,j} = \tau_j - \tau_i$. With the sound of speed $c$ I can then calculate the corresponding distance with $d_{i,j} = \Delta\tau_{i,j} \cdot c$.
With this knowledge I was hoping that I could somehow (for example by calculating the angles shown in the image) calculate the angle of the incoming plane wave.
Here is my notation:
$\varphi$ - Angle of the incoming wave 
$\varphi_{i,j}$ - Angle between the two corners $i$ and $j$
$M$ - Number of receiving elements (or corners) 
$m$ - Index of the $m$-th receiving element (corner) 
$d$ - length of each segment of the polygon
$d_{i,j}$ - See image
Image of the problem
Everything except to the angle of the incoming wave is given. The given example is for a number of three corners (elements) but a solution where the number of corners is a variable would be better since there are setups which need four or even more receiving elements.
I'd be pleased if someone would be able to help me here.
Thanks in advance.

It is not entirely clear what you want to calculate... Do you have the sound signals received on all points and do you want from there to compute the angle $\phi$ of the drawing? And does the sound consist of a pulse, or a continuous sine wave, or do we just assume a random signal?

The signal doesn't really matter. I just wanted to give a practical background to my problem. Exactly - I already processed the received signals and by that know the delay of the arrival between all the receiving elements. Since I know the sound of speed I can then calculate the distances $d_{i,j}$. Since I also know the distance between the receiving elements I can then calculate the angles shown in the image. And from that point I want to calculate the angle $\varphi$

I updated my question - I hope it's a little bit clearer now what I mean? @JosBergervoet

A least-squares fit to find $\varphi$ seems reasonable. Since the line between points $i$ and $j$ makes an angle $\varphi+(i+j)\pi/M$ with the incoming wave front, we need the best match between each $d_{i,j}$ from the observations and the actual path length difference $r_{ij}\sin(\varphi+(i+j)\pi/M)$ that is present for a certain $\varphi$. In that expression $r_{ij}$ stands for the distance between the two points involved, which is $2R\sin(\tfrac12|i-j|\pi/M)$ with $R$ the radius of the circle through the $M$ points.
So we have to minimize:
$$\begin{align}
 \chi^2 &= \sum_{i,j} \Big(d_{i,j} - r_{ij}\ \sin\big(\varphi+\frac{\pi (i+j)}{M}\big)\Big)^{\large 2}
\end{align}$$
For the case $M=3$ this simplifies a lot, for all $i,j$ we have $r_{ij}= \tfrac12 \sqrt3\,R$, and for $\chi^2$ we find:
$$\begin{align}
 \chi^2 &= C + A \cos\varphi + B\sin\varphi     \tag{1}
\\[5pt] \text{with}\ \ A&=  {\small \frac32}\ R\ ( d_{0,1}-d_{1,2}),
\\[5pt]  B&= {\small \frac12}\sqrt3\ R\ (-d_{0,1}-d_{1,2}+2d_{2,0})
\\[5pt] \text{and}\ \ C&= {\small \frac32}\,R^2 + d_{0,1}+d_{1,2}+d_{2,0}
\end{align}$$
It should be clear from $(1)$ that the minimum is achieved if the vector $(\cos\varphi, \sin\varphi)$ is in the direction $(-A,-B)$, which gives a unique angle. The constant $C$ is not needed.
(This angle can of course be expressed with the two-argument arctangent as $\text{atan2}({\small -B,-A})$, but there is some ambiguity in the order of arguments, compare [1], [2], [3]. Using ordinary $\arctan$ it would be either $\arctan(\frac{B}{A})$, or $\arctan(\frac{B}{A})+\pi$, for the cases $A<0$ and $A>0$ respectively, and special treatment for $A=0$ to avoid dividing by $0$.)
